# Having a list in a python class with a different name?

Tags: python, list, class, constructor

Here is the task: Write a class called LineUp.This class should contain
one (private) field (called acts) to store up to 30 acts. This field should be initialised in the constructor. 
A method add_act that takes an Act (keep in mind I've written code above this with 'Act' and that's all fine) as an argument and adds it to acts if there are fewer than 30 acts already, otherwise a message “The festival is full!” should be printed,
add a method toString or **str** which produces a nice string with full line-up,
add a method print which prints a nice string with the full line-up.
I'm assuming that the first point is asking for a list. I think I've found a way to have a list in a class, but it has the same name (LineUp, as opposed to 'acts'). Here's what I have

```
class LineUp(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.acts = []

    def add_act():
        if len(acts) >= 30:
            print("The festival is full!")
        else:
            acts.append(Act)

    def __str__(self):
        string = "LineUp" + str(LineUp)

    def println(self):
        print(__str__(self))
```

Thanks in advance! Keep in mind this is my first draft.

EDIT: should I actually use a dictionary, not a list? Know that in another file I'm testing this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't nee to inherit from `list` or get `acts` as parameter. To create a list for the class use `self.acts` in the constructor. You should also add `__repr__`

```
class LineUp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.acts = []

    def add_act(self, act):
        if len(self.acts) >= 30:
            print("The festival is full!")
        else:
            self.acts.append(act)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'LineUp{str(LineUp)}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'LineUp{str(LineUp)}'

    def println(self):
        print(f'LineUp acts:{[act for act in self.acts]}')
```

Notice that `str(LineUp)` will return something like `<class 'ExampleTest.LineUp'>`, you might want to edit it.

Comment: funnily enough I've just edited it like that before you answered, but thank you!

Comment: @nil In your code you extend `list` and doesn't use `self` when calling `acts`.